# JavaScript Adblocker detection - jsonip doesn't show

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im running a script to see if anyone is using Adblocker.

Script:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip"></script>
<p><a style="text-decoration: none;">&copy; Example.com</a></p>
<br>
<div class="tester" style="display:none"><a href="http://www.namecheap.com?aff=87222"><img src="http://files.namecheap.com/graphics/linkus/728x90-1.gif" height="90" width="728" border="0" alt="Namecheap"></a></div>
<script>
  if (document.getElementById("tester") == undefined) 
  { 
    document.write('<p><a style="text-decoration: none;">#Ban ');
    function getip(json){ document.write(json.ip); };
    document.write('</a></p>');
  }
</script>
```

It shows the text #Ban and a whitespace of course, but it doesnt say the IP.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://jsonip.appspot.com/?callback=getip doesn't exists

Comment: It does exist... Click it and it will show getip({"ip": "youriphere", "address":"youriphere"});

Comment: It didn't work yesterday

Comment: Hmm Well its fine now I just decided to debunk the idea i was using this for.